# If $a+\frac b2 + \frac c3+\frac d4+\frac e5=0$ , $ a+bx+cx^2+dx^3+ex^4=0$ has at least one real zero.

Tags: polynomials, roots

> $$
> \text{a,b,c,d,e }\in \text{R, and a}+\frac{\text{b}}{2}+\frac{\text{c}}{3}+\frac{\text{d}}{4}+\frac{\text{e}}{5}=0
> \\
> \text{Prove that a}+\text{bx}+\text{cx}^2+\text{dx}^3+\text{ex}^4=\text{0 has at least one real zero}.
> $$

The question is from *The Art and Craft of Problem Solving*. I can only observe that if we can prove there is an x such that f(x)*e<0, then we are done. But I can not use the first condition well.

Comment: The first condition has something to do with integration of your polynomial.

Comment: Ah, got it, thanks

Answer (score 2):

*Hint:* Consider $F(x)=ax+\dfrac{b}{2}x^2+\dfrac{c}{3}x^3+\dfrac{d}{4}x^4+\dfrac{e}{5}x^5$ and $f(x)=a+bx+cx^2+dx^3+ex^4$.

Comment: Good, so F(1)=0, that is F(x) has a real root. Would this imply that d/dx(F(x))=f(x) must have a real root also?

Comment: @NoChance, note that $F(0)=0$ and apply Rolle's theorem

Comment: Thank you very much.